# Save all images from all emails automatically

Tags: mail.app, email

I receive lots of jpeg files on my mail, and in order for me to save it on my desktop I have to save them one by one.

Is there any other way that I can save all the images without saving them one by one?

Comment: I assume you are using the standard mail program in OS X. Are these jpegs all attached to the same mail message or is it one jpeg per mail message?

Comment: have to check the name of the mail prog, im away at the moment in my laptop. yes it is attached to one email with 5 or more jpeg attachment.

Comment: You are using a MacBook of some sorts though?

Comment: mac book pro.. :(

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/367778/how-to-export-an-email-from-mail-application/367796#367796

Answer (score 4):

If you move your mouse into the header area of the message window (assuming you use Apple Mail), a segmented control appears at the lower end of the header, and one of the buttons shows a paperclip. Click on that, and a menu should appear, with one choice being "save all".

If you want to save all attachments from a number of messages simultaneously, my advice is to go into the Mail attachments folder inside the Library folder in your home directory. But here it will be hard to pick just the files you want, because the file names are not always helpful. Look for

Users/Username/Library/Mail Downloads

Users/Username/Library/Mail/Mail Downloads

If you can't see your Library folder, see:
[How to make your Library folder visible in the Finder in OS X 10.7 (Lion) or later](http://kb.mit.edu/confluence/display/istcontrib/How+to+make+your+Library+folder+visible+in+the+Finder+in+OS+X+10.7+%28Lion%29+or+later)

Answer (score 2):

You could use Automator for that.

Create a Automator action that will automatically extract and save all attachments to a folder that you specify.

First create a Folder where to save the JPEG files so you can find them afterwards.

Open Automator and do following

On left click on Mail that will show the mail actions.

Now find and just drag the following to the right side.

Choose your email account

Choose where to save the files

[image: automator]

Now click the Run on top Right and go and get a coffee :)

Comment: I have updated my answer with instructions how to

Comment: Great. thank you very much for helping me out. ill try once i get home. <3

Comment: If this worked for you check the answer so we do not have it popping up forever.

Comment: i just tried the using Automator as described above.it did not work and I got an OSStatus error -10000 result (not sure what that means). My OS is El Capitan. Any suggestions?