# How to export an email from Mail application?

Tags: mail.app, email

I would like to export one particular email to *.eml* , so I can save it on my disk and then manually attach to another message.

I am aware of those two options:

- export whole mailbox
- forward email as attachment

Neither of them meet my requirements, and this seems like really basic functionality.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually that functionality is beyond simple. Drag the email from the Mail.app window to the desktop. When you reach the desktop the pointer then contains acircular green "+"

Drop the email there and you now have a single message as an .eml file

Comment: great, thanks a lot. simple, yet not enough intuitive (at least for me..)

Comment: Yah, Apple is famous for that kind of interface. We have **all** been victims of this kind of "non-discoverable" UI

Answer (score 2):

**Harder way!** If you know the contents of the mail search for it in `~/Library/Mail`, and go to path like

```
~/Library/Mail/V6/<some-key>/INBOX.mbox/key/Data/2/5/Messages/52377.emlx
```

`V6` may be different for other versions of macOS or Mail. For partial emails, remote content might be needed to download first.

Comment: yeah... why would anyone want harder way? ;) besides, why .emlx, not .eml?

Comment: @Line If I hadn't written it there, you won't even comment. But it gives additional info. for example extracting all attachments is easier there than in UI. I dont know, raw vs export quality. Photos also distinguishes between JPG and JPEG while exporting unmodified original and otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Mail has this functionality. It is as simple as File > Save As > choose raw source for .eml format.